how to make a function inside a function can can only be called inside that function JavaScript
how to make a function inside a function can can only be called inside that function JavaScript
like

function idk(callback) {

    function test() {

        console.log("Test function called!");

    }

    const frozenTest = Object.freeze(test);

    callback(frozenTest);

}



// Usage

idk((tests) => {

    tests();

});

but when doing
idk((testing)=>{
  testing((
})

it can change names, im making a project so i dont want that
i tried a lot of ways but it can still be changed
i really needed to know how, if you guys can teach. Just teach me how to make a function that is only callable inside a function or how to make it so that it doesn't change the name of the function like the example test()

If you pass a function X as a parameter to function Y(someFunc) then Y can do someFunc() without knowing anything about X. It is YOU who passed X to Y. There is no way to achieve "hey Y, here is a function, but HA HA GOTCHA you can't call it". It would make no sense to me at all to have such a requirement, or to have such a limitation built into a language. Simply don't send X to Y if you don't want Y to be able to call it.

The function does not "change names".

Could you explain more what you mean by 'it can change names'?
